# $X_{n}$ converges in probability, $f$ is continuous, $f(X_{n})$ converges in probability

Tags: probability-theory

I am trying to show the following

> Let $X_{n}$ be a sequence of random variables which converge in probability to $X$. Show if $f$ is a continuous function on $\Bbb R$, then $f(X_{n}) \to f(X)$ in probability.

I think if we know $f$ is uniform continuous, then this will be quite trivial. I try to proceed from this point by using compact exhaustion, but it didn't work. Could someone give me help on this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A sequence $\{X_k\}_{k\in\Bbb N}$ of random variables converges in probability to $X$ if and only if for all subsequences $\left\{X_{k_n}\right\}_{n\in\Bbb N}$ there is a sub-subsequence $\left\{X_{k_{n_j}}\right\}_{j\in \Bbb N}$ such that $X_{k_{n_j}}\to X$ a.e.

Now, given a subsequence $\left\{ f(X_{k_n})\right\}_{n\in\Bbb N}$ of $\{f(X_k)\}_{k\in\Bbb N}$, there is a subsequence $X_{k_{n_j}}$ such that $X_{k_{n_j}}(\omega)\to X(\omega)$ for all $\omega$ in some set $E$ of probability $1$. By continuity, $f\left(X_{k_{n_j}}(\omega)\right)\to f(X(\omega))$ for all $\omega$ in $E$. This gives an almost-everywhere convergent subsequence of $\left\{ f(X_{k_n})\right\}_{n\in\Bbb N}$ to $f(X)$.